# "SSL connection error" in Firefox after updating to ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, firefox, ssl, google

I updated my laptop to 16.04.LTS but now I cannot open google, gmail, youtube, anything google related. It gives me "`SSL connection error`". I can open other sites just like before the updating. Can anyone help?

Thanks

p.s. I inherited this laptop from my son. Have no knowledge about ubuntu. So I would appreciate it greatly if you can provide step by step fixes in your answer. Thanks

Comment: It should say more than just "SSL connection error", for example something like "Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". SSL has some "moving parts", or parameters that the server and the client have to agree on to get it to work. Among those are the SSL/TLS protocol version, the chiffre and others. If for example the server only supports TLSv1.0 and the browser only supports TLSv1.2, they're "not talking the same language" and the site won't load. Please edit your question with the full and exact error message.

Comment: In general, it looks like the affected servers still use outdated security features that have been supported by your previous version of Firefox, but are no longer supported by the Firefox version that comes with Ubuntu 16.04. If that's the case, it next to always is the best decision not to use those sites anymore. Those security features (for example SSLv2 and SSLv3) were removed with good reason.